# Does Java have an NFC API for use on standard machines?

Tags: java, android, nfc, jsr257

I am looking to enable NFC operations between an Android phone and a PC. I have an NFC reader that connects to a PC via USB. I have read about the Contactless Communication API and this seems to be for mobile use only.

I need something that allows me to specify what COM port the NFC dongle is connected to and then deal with incoming/outgoing NCF packets. Can anyone suggest a Java based solution to me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which NFC reader you have.  I personally use one of these: http://www.nfc-reader.com/acr122.php which comes with an SDK and sample code in several languages including java.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use the SCL3711 Contactless Mobile Reader: http://www.identive-infrastructure.com/en/products-solutions/smart-card-readers-a-terminals/contactless-readers/scl3711

I will have to look into the one you mentioned.